Is there a way to call utility method in TEXT Thymeleaf template?
I have application aimed to transform API responses into human-readable text. For that purpose I call data from 3rd parties, build the model from it and run template against context through org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.
Example:
public Optional<String> process(String template, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
        thymeleafContext.setVariables(model);

        try {
            return Optional.of(templateEngine.process(template, thymeleafContext););
        } catch (TemplateProcessingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

For that purpose I have a number of plaintext Thymeleaf templates org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode#TEXT (keep note this) placed into separate .txt files.
Let's assume I have template like this: Born year: [[${bornYear}}]]. Now I need to cast the value of bornYear variable into specific pattern. For that purpose I have utility method like this
public class Utils {

    private Utils() {}

    public static String cast(String source, String pattern) {
        return "<implement me>";
    }
}

and I assume I can execute this utility method in the template. However I can not make it possible, at least I get exception on template processing.
What I tried:

Template Born year: [[${Utils.cast(bornYear, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}]].
Template Born year: [[${T(com.example.Utils).cast(bornYear, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}]]. This leads to org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden in this context.
Define Utils as Spring Bean and adjust template in a way Born year: [[${utils.cast(bornYear, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}]] or Born year: [[${@utils.cast(bornYear, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}]]. This leads to Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'Utils'.

TemplateResolver configuration:
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolve() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    return templateResolver;
}

My questions are:

Is that possible to call custom code considering I do use TemplateMode.TEXT?
If yes, how to do it in a right way?
Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

The way I would do this is...

Change utils to be a regular object:
 public class Utils {
     public String cast(String source, String pattern) {
         return "<implement me>";
     }
 }


Always put a utils onto your model:
 public Optional<String> process(String template, Map<String, Object> model) {
     Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
     model.put("utils", new Utils());
     thymeleafContext.setVariables(model);


In your template, use it like this:
Born year: [[${utils.cast(bornYear, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}]]




Another way you can do this, when instantiating your context add a ThymeleafEvaluationContext like this.  You will have to get access to your Spring ApplicationContext as well.
public Optional<String> process(String template, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
    context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME, new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, null));
    thymeleafContext.setVariables(model);

Then if you've annotated your utils class with @Component and made sure it is in a package that is being scanned by your configuration:
@Component
public class Utils {
    public String cast(String source, String pattern) {
        return "<implement me>";
    }
}

You will be able to access Beans in your templates like this:
Born year: [[${@utils.cast(bornYear, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}]]


Hi @Metroids, thank you for your input. It worked for me, but I'm just wondering if there any way to delegate context propagation to Spring so that there is no need to explicitly specify what classes to propagate? I was under impression that if a class is a part of Spring context (like declared as Component), it would be automatically propagated, but seems like this is not true.

If you want it to work that specific way, you should include that in your question... you'll need to include your spring configuration as well as how you've created your templateEngine.

Hi @Metroids, I have nothing specific in TemplateEngine configuration. I take it from application context in my service and then call #process(String template, Map<String, Object> model) method (described in the post). The only custom configuration I have is around templateResolver (also in the post).
Is there any specific TemplateEngine configuration you have in mind?
Thanks!

Alright, there is my best guess based on the information you supplied.

To call a utility method within a TEXT Thymeleaf template, you need to expose the utility class (or its methods) as part of the context variables so that Thymeleaf can recognize and use it.

Indeed, but any ideas how to make it properly? I left in the post what I tried and these options do not work for me.
